# How to get microphones and cameras devices?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get a list with all devices connected of my iphone (external and internal cameras and microphones). How can do that?

I'm using `AVCaptureDevices.devices()` but this method only return the default devices (front and back camera and build-in mic). Connecting  a bluetooth mic, I have the same return.

How can I get a list of available devices connected on my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. Using `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs` I can get all audio input devices and set it with `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredInput()`

Example:

```
let audioSession: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, options: .allowBluetooth)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch  {
        print("Error messing with audio session: \(error)")
    }

// All audio devices, bluetooth included
let audioInputDevices: [AVAudioSessionPortDescription] = audioSession.availableInputs!
```